# Exchange variables between two HTMLs and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session-variables

I'm trying to do a singup form to a mikrotik hotspot, this device do not allow to use PHP inside it, and I need to carry the variables from the device to a external php page that will save the costumer data and enable the trial in Hotspot...

Inside this device it hosted a HTML page with the following code

```
<html>
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body>
$(if chap-id)
<noscript>
<center><b>JavaScript required. Enable JavaScript to continue.</b></center>
</noscript>
$(endif)
<center>If you are not redirected in a few seconds, click 'continue' below<br>
<form name="redirect" action="http://10.2.3.100/cadastro.html?mac=$(mac)" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="mac" value="$(mac)">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="$(ip)">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="$(username)">
<input type="hidden" name="link-login" value="$(link-login)">
<input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value="$(link-orig)">
<input type="hidden" name="error" value="$(error)">
<input type="hidden" name="chap-id" value="$(chap-id)">
<input type="hidden" name="chap-challenge" value="$(chap-challenge)">
<input type="hidden" name="link-login-only" value="$(link-login-only)">
<input type="hidden" name="link-orig-esc" value="$(link-orig-esc)">
<input type="hidden" name="mac-esc" value="$(mac-esc)">
<input type="submit" value="continue">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
    document.redirect.submit();
//-->
</script></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've learned searching in google that I can send the variables to another page, by inserting it at the end of the URL, so ok, I will send the variable $MAC that I need to start the trial.

The page that receive it is a form page writen in HTML, I could not receive the variable in this page, I need to receive this variable to send to another page, in PHP the last one that will save the form in MySQL and after send to Mikrotik the link with the MAC of client to allow it to browse in internet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CADASTRO DE CLIENTES COM BANCO DE DADOS E PHP</title>
<style type="text/css">


</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type"text/javascript">
var qs = new QueryString();
var v1 = qs.get("mac");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = v1;
</script>


<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
  <table width="625" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="69">Nome:</td>
      <td width="546"><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="$(mac)" size="70" maxlength="60" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="70" maxlength="60" />
      <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Concluir meu Cadastro!" /> 
        <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar Campos preenchidos!" />
          <br />
          <span class="style1">* Campos com * s&atilde;o obrigat&oacute;rios!          </span></p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the PHP page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
// RECEBENDO OS DADOS DO PC DO USUARIO
   $mac=$_POST['mac'];

// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
$nome   = $_POST ["nome"];  //atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel  
$email  = $_POST ["email"]; //atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel

//Gravando no banco de dados !

//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","senha");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("cadhotspot",$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());



$query = "INSERT INTO `clientes` ( `nome` , `email`  ) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$sexo' '')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atenção.";
?>
Mac: <?php echo $mac ?><br>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=<?php echo $linkloginonly; ?>?dst=<?php echo $linkorigesc; ?>&username=T-<?php echo $mac; ?>">


</body>
</html>
```

The idea is, receive the MAC from customer device from the MikroTik to a HTML page hosted in it, after that load a HTML page with form to  customer singup and when the customer click in send it will write to mysql and send back the link below to Mikrotik

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=http://10.5.50.1?&username=T-<?php echo $mac; ?>">
```

My entire problem is to exchange the variables between HTML to HTML and after PHP pages.

Comment: Can you use javascript for example? Then you could read parameters in your url..

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `$_POST` data **NEVER** goes directly into a query.
`mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: I never touched into nothing written with PHP, I would like to learn for sure, but I have until tomorrow to leave this working.

Answer (score 0):

To forward the value of mac to php page try to add the following JS code inside the form. This will create a hidden field which when submitted will post the mac value to the php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var qs = new QueryString();
var v1 = qs.get("mac");
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="mac" value="' + v1  + '">')
</script>
```

There are some ending tags missing in the html pages.

Comment: Ok, I've inserted it into my cadastro.html, but what I insert in php to call this var?